# 数台程度の簡単なネットワーク構成図を書くのに便利なツールってありませんか？

Tags: network

数台程度の簡単なネットワーク構成図を書くのに便利なツールってありませんか？

Answer (score 3):

アプリケーションであれば「[Dia](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.en)」というダイアグラム描画ツールで作成できます(Windows/Mac OS X/Linux)。

**サンプル図**
[image: Network Map(Sample)]

Answer (score 1):

ツールはいろいろあると思いますので実際に試すのが一番だと思いますが
個人的には最近はCacooで書いてます。Visioほどじゃないけど、PowerPointよりはいろいろできて、操作が簡単。

あと nwdiag はテキストで書かれたコードを図に変換するツールでこれもたまに使います。
いちいち線を引いたりするのが面倒に感じるクチなので、勝手に図を作ってくれるのが嬉しいです。